# text editing with macros

Tags: text, macros, text-editor

I run into situations where I have to repeat a single line of text with some minor editing.

For example: 
1. insert into table_name (col_one, col_two) values (val_1, val_2);
2. insert into table_name (col_one, col_two) values (val_3, val_4);
3. insert into table_name (col_one, col_two) values (val_5, val_6);
and so on... (1000 records)

I mean, I will only type the first query and write a macro using the text editor to generate the required number of queries.
Hope you get the picture.

Please suggest a better text editor for this purpose. As I have already tried and failed with Ultraedit/Textpad. Maybe I am doing something wrong, as I cudnt get Vim to do this either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the example given where only the numbers change, this should be possible using the [Zeus](http://www.zeusedit.com) editor and a macro script. For example this [numbers](http://www.zeusedit.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=2092) script does something very similar.

To achieve the required result take the *numbers* script from above and make some minor changes to create an *odd numbers* and *even numbers* script.

Then column mark the 1000 lines of the *odd column* and run the *odd numbers* script. Then column mark the 1000 lines of the *even column* and run the *even numbers* script.

Answer (score 0):

Choices would be Vim or Emacs. Eg. Emacs offer macros and regular expressions, so you should be able to do what you want. Might be non-obvious though.

Comment: I am not very comfortable with Vim/Emacs. Can you send me a link please ?

Comment: @user258321 see my answer for how to do this specifically using emacs

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem might be more easily solved if you use a shell script to generate the text, rather than macros in a text editor.

Answer (score 0):

An editor is probably the wrong tool here - if you want to generate all those insert statements, you are probably better off writing a small program in a scripting language like perl or python.

Comment: that is what I am doing now, using python. But it is a quite generic problem. There must be an even quicker way.

Answer (score 0):

Just about any text editor will let you copy lines and edit them, certainly vim.

The right way to tackle this is to do this programatically: create a template file that generates the text file you want.  m4, a widely used macro-language is well-suited to this task, since you can mix text and macros freely. Cf. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M4_(computer_language)

E.g. (untested)

```
define(`txt`, "$1. insert into table_name (col_one, col_two) values (val_$2, val_$3);")
forloop(`i',1,1000,txt(i,eval(2*i-1),eval(2*i)))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting this because the OP asked for a link for how this can be done in Vim or Emacs in one of the comments

```
;; First set a special variable used for counting in macros to an initial value of 1
C-x C-k C-c 1  

;;type your text but use <C-x C-k C-i> in place of the numbers
;;<C-x C-k C-i> inserts the value of the counting var and automatically increments it by 1
insert into table_name (col_one, col_two) values (val_<C-x C-k C-i>, val_<C-x C-k C-i>)

;;repeat your macro 1000 times.
M-1000 C-x C-e
```